# Is it possible to have more than 1 MySQL database in my WordPress blog?

Tags: database, sql, installation

On first launch, WordPress prompts you to input your MySQL database username, password etc.  Then I can start working from dashboard.

Is it possible for WordPress to have more than one database?

If yes, what is the possible example for having 2-3 databases?  When would you need more than one db?

**Or the working rule is: one blog - one db? If you have 2-3 blogs, can you manage them from the SAME dashboard!? And each must of course have 1 db?**

Comment: The question is: What do you need 2-3 databases for? Please file an [edit] with that info. Additionally, please read about "WordPress Multisite" or "WordPress Network" on Codex.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have more than one database, this type of set-up is for large traffic heavy sites and you would want to use something like http://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/ . This is outside the scope of the vast majority of WordPress sites.

You can manage a multitude of blogs from 1 db if you want using  http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network. The option is up to you, the bare minimum is 1 db per install.

Answer (score 1):

> or the working rule is: one blog - one db?

Kind of... It would be one blog - one set of *db tables*.  When you install WordPress, you will give the required db tables a prefix. Using a second prefix would allow you to have a second WP installation running in the *same* database.  And a third, fourth, and so on.

> if you have 2-3 blogs, you can manage them from SAME dashboard!? and each must of course have 1 db?

In a basic install of WP, no. While you can have multiple WP blogs in a single db, you can only manage one blog from one dashboard.

That said,  you could use [WordPress multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), but that's more involved that a standard/basic install.  Also, there are some [third party products that allow you to manage multiple installs through one dashboard](http://sixrevisions.com/wordpress/tools-manage-multiple-wordpress-sites-one-location/), but that's not WP by itself. Both of these options would still only require one database.